# How to display image from datagridview to picturebox?

Tags: c#, datagridview, picturebox

I need some help to display images from my datagridview to my picturebox, can someone please help me? I'm very new to this. To this site as well.

I've used this to save the images

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] imageBt = null;
        FileStream fstream = new FileStream(this.afbeelding_txt.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fstream);
        imageBt = br.ReadBytes((int)fstream.Length);

        string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=username;password=password";
        string Query = "INSERT INTO project.auto (kenteken, merk, type, kleur, deuren, prijscategorie, afbeelding) VALUES('" + this.kenteken_txt.Text + "','" + this.merk_txt.Text + "','" + this.type_txt.Text + "','" + this.kleur_txt.Text + "','" + this.deuren_txt.Text + "','" + this.prijscategorie_txt.Text + "',@IMG) ;";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conDataBase.Open();

            cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@IMG", imageBt));

            myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Opgeslagen");
            while (myReader.Read())
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        load_table();
    }
```

And the following is to show the datagridview

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

            kenteken_txt.Text = row.Cells["kenteken"].Value.ToString();
            merk_txt.Text = row.Cells["merk"].Value.ToString();
            type_txt.Text = row.Cells["type"].Value.ToString();
            kleur_txt.Text = row.Cells["kleur"].Value.ToString();
            deuren_txt.Text = row.Cells["deuren"].Value.ToString();
            prijscategorie_txt.Text = row.Cells["prijscategorie"].Value.ToString();
            afbeelding_txt.Text = row.Cells["afbeelding"].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Besides this code the picturebox isn't mentioned.

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        dlg.Filter = "PNG Files(*.png)|*.png|JPG Files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        dlg.Title = "Selecteer auto afbeelding.";
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string picPath = dlg.FileName.ToString();
            afbeelding_txt.Text = picPath;
            pictureBox1.ImageLocation = picPath;
        }
    }
```

The image is shown in the datagridview in this column:

```
    afbeelding_txt.Text = row.Cells["afbeelding"].Value.ToString();
```

I tried :

```
    pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(row.Cells["afbeelding"].Value.ToString());
```

And got the following error :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: System.Byte[]

Comment: Where is your picturebox control?

Comment: how you bind the dataGridView1? is there any column to show the image? and you don't need to use `ExecuteReader` for insert, use [ExecuteNonQuery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand.html#connector-net-examples-mysqlcommand-executenonquery)

Comment: Can you type the column content? Is this a filepath or it is a byte array that represent the image itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If in the column there is the file path of the image, use the [Image.FromFile method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(row.Cells["afbeelding"].Value.ToString());
```

Else, if in the column there is directly the image value you can use the [FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10454807/838405), in your case:

```
var data = (Byte[])(row.Cells["afbeelding"].Value);
var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
pictureBox1.Image= Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: The images are saved in the database as BLOB - 64 KiB. I don't know if that changes anything?

Comment: try the second solution

Comment: Thank you so much! It's finally showing the image in the picturebox! One more question though, it's only showing a little bit of the image in the first row, and even less of the second. Does this have something to do with the size or something?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, maybe you have to set the `SizeMode` property: `pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;`