# Insert picturebox image to Sqlite db & retrieval that in c#

Tags: c#, image, sqlite, picturebox

Excuse me I can't find my question answer in the site.

I have a project that give and retrieval of some information (text type data) by using a Sqlite database.

But I want add a picture to the one of columns and retrieval that by clicking on the field of that image (docImage in below code).

Can you help me please?

```
private void LoadData()
{
    SetConnection(); 
    sql_con.Open();

    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    string CommandText = "select id, docImage, letternum, name, female, personnamber, organname, officename, numberofdoc, numberofbox, ticket, docdate   from  mains";
    DB = new SQLiteDataAdapter(CommandText,sql_con);
    DS.Reset();
    DB.Fill(DS);
    DT= DS.Tables[0];
    Grid.DataSource = DT;
    sql_con.Close();

}

private void SetConnection()
{
    sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=DemoT.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");

}

private void ExecuteQuery(string txtQuery)
{
    SetConnection();
    sql_con.Open();

    sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
    sql_cmd.CommandText=txtQuery;

    sql_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql_con.Close();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadData();
}

private void Add()
{
    string txtSQLQuery = "insert into  mains (docImage, letternum, name, female, personnamber, organname, officename, numberofdoc, numberofbox, ticket, docdate ) values ('" + txtDesc11.Text + "','" + txtDesc.Text + "','" + txtDesc2.Text + "','" + txtDesc3.Text + "','" + txtDesc4.Text + "','" + txtDesc5.Text + "','" + txtDesc6.Text + "','" + txtDesc7.Text + "','" + txtDesc8.Text + "','" + txtDesc9.Text + "','" + txtDesc10.Text + "')";

    ExecuteQuery(txtSQLQuery);       
}   

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Add();

    LoadData();
    btnAdd.Enabled = false;
    btnNew.Enabled = true;
    btnEdit.Enabled = false;

    txtDesc.Text = string.Empty;
    txtDesc2.Text = string.Empty;       
}
```

Comment: What is your datatype for "docImage" field? it should be "BLOB" datatype

Comment: Please refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/625485/1849024

Comment: yes .. thats BLOB type data . & i changed txtDesc10.Text to picturebox1.Image . but thats not work ..

Comment: does your code insert into sqlite? you have problem displaying right?

Comment: please check this answer also http://stackoverflow.com/a/10454807/1849024

Comment: check this page: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/196618/C-SQLite-Storing-Images

Comment: when i use this code , at the field of docimage , i see someting like " Array[] " . . but i dont know whats this means .. And i cant retivel any image ..

Comment: this example ( codeproject.com/Articles/196618/C-SQLite-Storing-Images)..is not a sqlite example .. i test that .. thank you Behzad

Comment: any body can answer on my project codes ?:(