# Parameter is not valid while reading image

Tags: c#, sql, windows

I want to read image from database and show in picture box. I tried sample example it runs perfectly.But when I use that code in my project then it not works shows that error "Parameter is not valid".please let me know if anyone have solution.thanks in advance.

```
 string ID = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT NEW_DRAWING FROM PO_ITEM WHERE ID='"+ID+"'";
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        reader.Read();

            byte[] img = ((byte[])reader[0]);
            if (img == null)
                pictureBox1.Image = null;
            else
            {
                  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,true);
            }
```

Comment: what is the value of ID ? is it non  empty ?

Comment: Store one image on disk _and_ in the database, load both and compare the `byte[]` you receive. If they're equal, you know the problem is the image data itself; if they are different, there's a problem with either how you store or retrieve the data.

Comment: it represents value of row id..no its not empty

Comment: Have you tried resetting the position of the `MemoryStream` after writing to it? Just add `ms.Position = 0;` after calling `Write`. As an aside, now would be a good time to use parameterized SQL rather than building SQL dynamically.

Comment: Might help you -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667818/error-parameter-is-not-valid-while-converting-bytes-into-image

Comment: Hi C.Evenhuis,I tested, both shows different bytes for same image while reading when I insert image byte values is 58053 and while reading it read 9

Comment: hi daisy,but its not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms,true); this one

Comment: So, you just changed the code in your post. Does the same exception get thrown in the same place? If so, how did you write the data to the database in the first place?

Comment: By the way, why not call `ExecuteScalar` if you only want to retrieve one value?  That's what it's for.

Comment: Also, why call `Read` and then test `HasRows`? There's no point to doing both. `Read` is going to return the same value as `HasRows` anyway. You ought to learn what this code you copied and pasted off the web actually does. Then you might understand why it works or doesn't.

Comment: now I have changed it  but still getting same problem

Comment: changed but not working

Comment: This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454595/loading-picturebox-image-from-database?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Solved...there is wrong when I was inserting image in table..thanks to all

Answer (score -2):

Image.FromStream() usually takes single parameter, that is MemoryStream.

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);
 pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: There are overloads that have bool parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.110).aspx